# Cant get mysql procedure to work - syntax error

Tags: mysql

I'm wrote this mysql procedure for inserting customer billing details into an ecommerce database.

If i run this in phpmyadmin, it throws errors for any semicolons. I removed the semicolons but it gives the following error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE addr_id INT UNSIGNED ... at line 4

I've never worked with procedures before but i double checked the syntax and can't figure out the error.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE addCustomer(email VARCHAR(60), status VARCHAR(15), bill_pin_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED, bill_addr VARCHAR(175), name VARCHAR(60), tel VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
DECLARE em_id INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE addr_id INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE cust_id INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE sql_error TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET sql_error = true;


--check if customer email already exists
SELECT id INTO em_id FROM email_list WHERE email = email;

-- not sure of the return value, haven't tested it
IF em_id = 1 THEN

  -- if emails exists check if customer exists
  SELECT id INTO cust_id FROM customer WHERE email_list_id = em_id;
  IF cust_id = 1 THEN

    -- customer must have address information
    SELECT address_id INTO addr_id from customer_addr
        INNER JOIN address on address_id = address.id
        WHERE customer_id = cust_id and address = bill_addr;
  END IF
END IF

START TRANSACTION;

IF (em_id = 0) THEN

  -- if email doesn't exist, no customer no address - simple insert
  INSERT INTO email_list (email, status) VALUES (email, status);
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO em_id;

  INSERT INTO customer (email_list_id, full_name, phone)
      VALUES (em_id, name, tel);
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO cust_id;

  INSERT INTO address (pincode_id, address) VALUES (bill_pin_id, bill_addr);
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO addr_id;

  INSERT INTO customer_addr (address_id, customer_id)
      VALUES (addr_id, cust_id);

ELSE
  UPDATE email_list SET status = status where id = em_id;
  UPDATE customer SET full_name = name, phone = tel WHERE id = cust_id;
  UPDATE address SET pincode_id = bill_pin_id, address = bill_addr;
END IF

IF sql_error = FALSE THEN
  COMMIT;
  SELECT 'SUCCESS';
ELSE
  ROLLBACK;
  SELECT 'FAILED';
END IF

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: phpmyadmin does not understand the `DELIMITER` directive, but it should have a way to select the statement delimiter, possibly a small drop-down or text box.  The error suggests that your delimiter is not set.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution, I added some missing semicolons and spaces in some comments.

```
CREATE addCustomer(email VARCHAR(60), status VARCHAR(15), bill_pin_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED, bill_addr VARCHAR(175), name VARCHAR(60), tel VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
DECLARE em_id INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE addr_id INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE cust_id INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE sql_error TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET sql_error = true;


-- check if customer email already exists
SELECT id INTO em_id FROM email_list WHERE email = email;

-- not sure of the return value, haven't tested it
IF em_id = 1 THEN

  -- if emails exists check if customer exists
  SELECT id INTO cust_id FROM customer WHERE email_list_id = em_id;
  IF cust_id = 1 THEN

    -- customer must have address information
    SELECT address_id INTO addr_id from customer_addr
        INNER JOIN address on address_id = address.id
        WHERE customer_id = cust_id and address = bill_addr;
  END IF;
END IF;

START TRANSACTION;

IF (em_id = 0) THEN

  -- if email doesn't exist, no customer no address - simple insert
  INSERT INTO email_list (email, status) VALUES (email, status);
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO em_id;

  INSERT INTO customer (email_list_id, full_name, phone)
      VALUES (em_id, name, tel);
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO cust_id;

  INSERT INTO address (pincode_id, address) VALUES (bill_pin_id, bill_addr);
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO addr_id;

  INSERT INTO customer_addr (address_id, customer_id)
      VALUES (addr_id, cust_id);

ELSE
  UPDATE email_list SET status = status where id = em_id;
  UPDATE customer SET full_name = name, phone = tel WHERE id = cust_id;
  UPDATE address SET pincode_id = bill_pin_id, address = bill_addr;
END IF;

IF sql_error = FALSE THEN
  COMMIT;
  SELECT 'SUCCESS';
ELSE
  ROLLBACK;
  SELECT 'FAILED';
END IF;

END
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I corrected line 1 to create procedure and ran the code -- #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: its coming back to the same error. something to do with declare or begin statement

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by executing the entire procedure via mysql console

It accepted it without any errors. I then accessed the procedure from phpmyadmin routines tab and exported the statement.

The only difference i could find is this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addCustomer`(
    IN `email` VARCHAR(60),
    IN `status` VARCHAR(15),
    IN `bill_pin_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    IN `bill_addr` VARCHAR(175),
    IN `name` VARCHAR(60),
    IN `tel` VARCHAR(15)
)

-- regular procedure statements

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I had made some errors with not adding semicolons after if statements as pointed out by Domingo Sambo.

I deleted the procedure and tested it again adding it via phpmyadmin query box and its working perfectly.